# npm ERR! missing script: dev

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm, containers

I have a Jenkins container.
With node v7.2.1 and npm 5.6.0, installed by the command:
`apk add nodejs-current`

Out of the container, I can run the `npm run dev` command directly in the folder containing the package.json. It has node v8.11.1 and npm 5.6.0 and build sucess.

Returning to container jenkins
In Jenkins Build, it runs shell ...
command in the same package.json folder:
`npm run dev`

My package.json:

`"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline --hot",
    "production": "webpack --progress -p"
  }`

**npm ERR! missing script: dev**

Build Failed

I saw some solutions here, but I did not succeed.I believe my error is due to the version of nodejs.
**If anyone knows how to upgrade nodejs to 8.11.1 or reinstall version 8.11.1 inside the jenkins container.** Try nvm, n... fail

Sorry for my english. Google translate save me xD

Comment: Check your WORKDIR & ENTRYPOINT - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir